# How do I handle Context Null?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, maui

#### ViewHandler - InvalidOperationException : `Context cannot be null here`

###### `When does the exception happen` : *navigating to page with `customized controls`*

`Platform` : *Android*
`SDK` : *8.x Preview Version*
`Occurred Location??` :  [*ViewHandlerOfT.Android - Line12*](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Core/src/Handlers/View/ViewHandlerOfT.Android.cs#L12)

```cs
// ViewHandlerOfT.Android - Line12
public partial class ViewHandler<TVirtualView, TPlatformView> : IPlatformViewHandler
{
    ...
    public Context Context => MauiContext?.Context ?? throw new InvalidOperationException($"Context cannot be null here");
    ...
}
```

`Why asking` : I've seen questions from Stack Overflow and MAUI issues, but `I couldn't get an answer`.

### Question

- If you don't understand, please `let me know what you need`.
- There is `no Handler registered` to customized control. `Does it need handler`?
- How to `(Context)null check?`
- Please let me know `when the context can be null`

Update 2023.11.15
`Sample link` : https://github.com/SSstupid/IDontKnow-This-/pull/5

Comment: Did you mean you don't have any cusom handler? In addition, can you show the code about your custom control and navigation? If you can provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that will be great.

Comment: >  you don't have any cusom handler? => No, I have no custom handler, and  i writing   example

Comment: When I cloned your git, the SampleContextCanNotBeNull project wasn't in it.

Comment: Liyun Zhang - MSFT
It is in the 'ContextCanNotBeNullSample' branch, I will merge to main, Sorry

Comment: 2023.11.15 22:28 update: …sample branch merge to main

Comment: All right. I have copied code to test but the exception is can't find handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <!-- <Canvas >...-->
            <local:SampleBorder />
        <!-- ... </Canvas >-->
    </ContentPage.Content>
    
    <!--It will be not Throw Context null issue => if any control here -->
    <StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    <!--It will be not Throw Context null issue => if any control here -->
```

This is because the `<ContentPage.Content>` can only be set as an element. `<StackLayout>` will replace the `<local:SampleBorder />` render in the page, so it will not cause exception.

When I clone your project, I can reproduce your problem. But if I copy your code to a new maui project. I will get the **HandlerNotFoundException**. I used **Visual Studio Version 17.9.0 Preview 1.0**.

But if I remove the code about the **SKCanvasView** and make the `SampleBorder` extend `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.AbsoluteLayout`, it will work.

In addition: the Nuget Packages about SkiaSharp don't support .net 8. They may cause this error.

Finally, did you want to custom a layout in the maui? If so, you can refer to this issue : [Custom layout example for .NET Maui?](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/8619). In my test, the `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility` have some problem.